# SpecFlow - Generation error: Interface cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow

I was cleaning up an inherited test automation project and fixed some spelling errors in scenario names in a SpecFlow feature file, then started receiving this error:

```
CS1029
#error Generation error: Interface cannot be resolved: TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.UnitTestProvider.IUnitTestGeneratorProvider('custom')
```

There is no customer unit test provider.

Things I have tried:

- Closing VS, killed all the SpecFlow temp files, restarting VS
- Killed the *.feature file and recreating it.
- Rolled back to a previous version of SpecFlow
- Commented out all scenario tags
- Followed the steps in this article: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Troubleshooting-Visual-Studio-Integration

Now, all my feature files are showing that error, not just the one I fixed spelling errors in.  I'm using VS2015.  Any ideas what could cause this error?

Comment: Do you have any custom plugins? Could you post your complete specflow section of the app.config?

Comment: And which version of SpecFlow+ are you using?

Comment: @AndreasWillich, Per below, was using 2.2, reverted back to 2.1 and the problem went away.  The app.config section looks like this:

  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest.2010" runtimeProvider="TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.MsTest2010RuntimeProvider,TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
  </specFlow>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be some issue with corruption of SpecFlow 2.2 feature files.

With 2.2, deleting and recreating the feature files did not solve the problem.  Reverting to 2.1 did.

After reverting to 2.1, the errors still occurred UNTIL I deleted the feature file then recreated it.  I had 8 feature files, all reporting the error.  After deleting and recreating each one, all 8 errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

In the app.config, make sure the unit test provider name you're using corresponds to an actual test framework. Ex:

```
<specFlow>
   <unitTestProvider name="nUnit" />
</specFlow>
```

My suspicion is that the tests were generated using a valid app.config, but the app.config is no longer valid. When you changed the feature file(s), it caused it to attempt to regenerate the tests using an invalid test framework provider name, leading to the error message you're seeing.

Comment: It had been MsTest.2010.  I changed it to the more generic MsTest, which didn't clear up the issue and have since changed it back to MsTest.2010.  Additionally, I had rebuilt the project just a couple of hours ago and then it built fine.  I've seen this error happen one other time with an invalid tag applied.  Removing the tag cleared up the problem. But there are no tags in this case.